# Decode data in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, unknown-data

I am trying to decode data packet in Wireshark but I don't know what type of encoding is that
[image]

Comment: All we can tell is that it's a UDP broadcast on a high port... maybe check the app that's sending the packets?

Comment: check it for what?

Comment: Well without an obvious structure, the easiest way to determine the packet content is to analyse the program that's sending it.